# All command line arguments to main

Tags: c, memory, program-entry-point

I was wondering what are all command line arguments to main function (in C specifically, but I am guessing this would apply to all languages regardless)? In my compilers class I heard an instructor briefly mention (possibly I misheard or misunderstood that) that there is more to main() arguments than typically mentioned, specifically that at negative offset from argv pointer one can access some information. I could not find anything by Googling or in a couple of textbooks I have. I wrote this small program in C to try. Here are some questions:

1) While loop runs 32 time before seg faulting. Why are there 32 parameters in total, where can I find specification on them and why are there 32 of them not another quantity?

Information that's printed out is all about the system: pwd, term session info, user info and all that.

2) Is there anything that is put onto the stack before main? In a typical call procedure arguments to the function are put on the stack before the return address (give or take canaries and other stuff). When a program is called by the shell is the process the same and where can I read about this? I'd really like to know how shell calls a program and what's the memory layout compared to in-program stack layout.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    void * argall = argv[0];

    printf("argc=%d\n", argc);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 32) {
    //while (argall) { // tried this to find out that it seg faults at i=32
        printf("arg%d %s\n", i, (char* ) argall);
        i++;
        argall = argv[i];
    }

    printf("negative pointers\n");
    // I don't think dereferencing in this part is quite right, but I am 
    // getting chars since I am reading bytes. Output of below code is.
    // How come it is alphabet?
    // I tried reading int values and (char*) for string, but got nothing useful.
    /*
    arg -1 o
    arg -2 n 
    arg -3 m
    arg -4 l
    arg -5 k
    */
    printf("arg -1 %c\n", (char) argv-1);
    printf("arg -2 %c\n", (char) argv-2);
    printf("arg -3 %c\n", (char) argv-3);
    printf("arg -4 %c\n", (char) argv-4);
    printf("arg -5 %c\n", (char) argv-5);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks a lot! Sorry about a long post.

Update:here is the output that comes from the while loop:

```
argc=1
arg0 ./main-testing.o
arg1 (null)
arg2 TERM_PROGRAM=iTerm.app
arg3 SHELL=/bin/bash
arg4 TERM=xterm-256color
arg5 CLICOLOR=1
arg6 TMPDIR=/var/folders/d0/<redacted>
arg7 Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/private/<redacted>
arg8 OLDPWD=/Users/me/problems
arg9 USER=me
arg10 COMMAND_MODE=unix2003
arg11 SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/t<redacted>
arg12 _<redacted>
arg13 LSCOLORS=ExFxBxDxCxegedabagacad
arg14 PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
arg15 PWD=/Users/me/problems/c
arg16 LANG=en_CA.UTF-8
arg17 ITERM_PROFILE=Default
arg18 XPC_FLAGS=0x0
arg19 PS1=\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\]\h:\[\033[33;1m\]\w\[\033[m\]$
arg20 XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
arg21 SHLVL=1
arg22 COLORFGBG=7;0
arg23 HOME=/Users/me
arg24 ITERM_SESSION_ID=w0t0p0
arg25 LOGNAME=me
arg26 _=./main-testing.o
arg27 (null)
arg28 executable_path=./main-testing.o
arg29
arg30
arg31
```

Comment: What were the exact words of your instructor? There aren't any 'hidden' arguments before `argv`.

Comment: I don't quite remember the words, I am sorry. What I understood is that there is some information that can be accessed before argv at negative offset. I may have heard wrong, but I am really curios. Since I can read it with negative offset, the space is clearly mine (belongs to the program), so I am interested to know how far and what I can get by going negative up the stack.

Comment: Accessing `argv[i]` outside the range where `i` is `0...argc` is undefined behavior (UB).  That's it.  You might find something useful on select machines sometimes, code may crash.  It is UB.  C does does not specify what happens when code attempts it.

Comment: Sorry, what is UB? Thank you.

Comment: Undefind Behaviour. You cannot just access random bits of memory and draw conclusions from it. Just because it doesn't crash until a certain point does not mean that the data is valid (though some of it does happen to be in your case). That is, your premise and conclusions are flawed. Having said that, the C standard does define a third parameter to `main` in some cases: "char *envp[], that points to a null-terminated array of pointers to char, each of which points to a string that provides information about the environment for this execution of the program"

Comment: Ah, interesting. So there is nothing predefined here, whatever 32 values I am getting is not something you should be expecting in every case? In my case since I am on Mac OS I have that, but on my Linux box it may be different? I just thought that there is maybe a spec and something like this is in fact defined. I tried searching for it, but failed to find.

Comment: What you are printing in the loop after the `arv` entries are the environment variables (up to the `null`). The C standard defines them as being passed into `main` as a third parameter. Many implementations put the env vars immediately after the `argv` strings. But that is implementation dependent and should not be relied on.

Comment: @kaylum: the C standard certainly does not define a third parameter to main.

Comment: @rici Yeah, you are right. It's in the common extensions section of the standard. So "defined" is not the right word but perhaps referenced.

Comment: I added comments to other answers. I clarified with the instructor and confirmed what other people supposed: I did not hear it right. There is in fact nothing useful before argv at negative offset (in C at least). Thanks again, I still learnt a lot of new things about this call and got some more stuff to read. Very cool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be using a Mac.  On a Mac, you get 4 bits of data.

You can use the alternative declaration for `main()` of:

```
int main(int argcv, char **argv, char **envp)
```

and you will then be able to list the environment, as you did by accessing beyond the end of the argument list.  The environment follows the arguments, and is also terminated by a null pointer.

Then a Mac has some more data after the environment (you can see `executable_path=…` in your output).  You can find some information about that at Wikipedia under [Entry Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point#C_and_C.2B.2B), which refers to [The `char *apple[]` Argument Vector](http://unixjunkie.blogspot.com/2006/02/char-apple-argument-vector.html):

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp, char **applev)
```

I'm not aware of any standardization for what goes before the `argv` vector.  Accessing them as single characters is unlikely to be useful.  I'd print the data as addresses and look for patterns.

This is some code I wrote a few years ago for trying to find the argument list from `environ`; it works up until you modify the environment by adding a new variable, which changes where `environ` points:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* putenv(), setenv() */

extern char **environ;  /* Should be declared in <unistd.h> */

/*
** The object of the exercise is: given just environ (since that is all
** that is available to a library function) attempt to find argv[0] (and
** hence argc).
**
** On some platforms, the layout of memory is such that the number of
** arguments (argc) is available, followed by the argument vector,
** followed by the environment vector.
**
**          argv                            environ
**            |                                |
**            v                                v
** | argc | argv0 | argv1 | ... | argvN | 0 | env0 | env1 | ... | envN | 0 |
**
** This applies to:
** -- Solaris 10 (32-bit, 64-bit SPARC)
** -- MacOS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard, 32-bit and 64-bit)
** -- Linux (RHEL 5 on x86/64, 32-bit and 64-bit)
**
** Sadly, this is not quite what happens on the other two Unix
** platforms.  The value preceding argv0 seems to be a 0.
** -- AIX 6.1          (32-bit, 64-bit)
** -- HP-UX 11.23 IA64 (32-bit, 64-bit)
**       Sub-standard POSIX support (no setenv()) and C99 support (no %zd).
**
** NB: If putenv() or setenv() is called to add an environment variable,
** then the base address of environ changes radically, moving off the
** stack onto heap, and all bets are off.  Modifying an existing
** variable is not a problem.
**
** Spotting the change from stack to heap is done by observing whether
** the address pointed to by environ is more than 128 K times the size
** of a pointer from the address of a local variable.
**
** This code is nominally incredibly machine-specific - but actually
** works remarkably portably.
*/

typedef struct Arguments
{
    char   **argv;
    size_t   argc;
} Arguments;

static void print_cpp(const char *tag, int i, char **ptr)
{
    uintptr_t p = (uintptr_t)ptr;
    printf("%s[%d] = 0x%" PRIXPTR " (0x%" PRIXPTR ") (%s)\n",
            tag, i, p, (uintptr_t)(*ptr), (*ptr == 0 ? "<null>" : *ptr));
}

enum { MAX_DELTA = sizeof(void *) * 128 * 1024 };

static Arguments find_argv0(void)
{
    static char *dummy[] = { "<unknown>", 0 };
    Arguments args;
    uintptr_t i;
    char **base = environ - 1;
    uintptr_t delta = ((uintptr_t)&base > (uintptr_t)environ) ? (uintptr_t)&base - (uintptr_t)environ : (uintptr_t)environ - (uintptr_t)&base;
    if (delta < MAX_DELTA)
    {
        for (i = 2; (uintptr_t)(*(environ - i) + 2) != i && (uintptr_t)(*(environ - i)) != 0; i++)
            print_cpp("test", i, environ-i);
        args.argc = i - 2;
        args.argv = environ - i + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        args.argc = 1;
        args.argv = dummy;
    }

    printf("argc    = %zd\n", args.argc);
    for (i = 0; i <= args.argc; i++)
        print_cpp("argv", i, &args.argv[i]);

    return args;
}

static void print_arguments(void)
{
    Arguments args = find_argv0();
    printf("Command name and arguments\n");
    printf("argc    = %zd\n", args.argc);
    for (size_t i = 0; i <= args.argc; i++)
        printf("argv[%zd] = %s\n", i, (args.argv[i] ? args.argv[i] : "<null>"));
}

static int check_environ(int argc, char **argv)
{
    size_t n = argc;
    size_t i;
    unsigned long delta = (argv > environ) ? argv - environ : environ - argv;
    printf("environ = 0x%lX; argv = 0x%lX (delta: 0x%lX)\n", (unsigned long)environ, (unsigned long)argv, delta);
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        print_cpp("chkv", i, &argv[i]);
    if (delta > (unsigned long)argc + 1)
        return 0;

    for (i = 1; i < n + 2; i++)
    {
        printf("chkr[%zd] = 0x%lX (0x%lX) (%s)\n", i, (unsigned long)(environ - i), (unsigned long)(*(environ - i)),
                (*(environ-i) ? *(environ-i) : "<null>"));
        fflush(0);
    }
    i = n + 2;
    printf("chkF[%zd] = 0x%lX (0x%lX)\n", i, (unsigned long)(environ - i), (unsigned long)(*(environ - i)));
    i = n + 3;
    printf("chkF[%zd] = 0x%lX (0x%lX)\n", i, (unsigned long)(environ - i), (unsigned long)(*(environ - i)));
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("Before setting environment\n");
    if (check_environ(argc, argv))
        print_arguments();

    //putenv("TZ=US/Pacific");
    setenv("SHELL", "/bin/csh", 1);

    printf("After modifying environment\n");
    if (check_environ(argc, argv) == 0)
        printf("Modifying environment messed everything up\n");
    print_arguments();

    putenv("CODSWALLOP=nonsense");

    printf("After adding to environment\n");
    if (check_environ(argc, argv) == 0)
        printf("Adding environment messed everything up\n");
    print_arguments();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jonathan. This is a really cool piece of code, I am still playing around with it. I also spoke to my instructor and clarified. I think I misunderstood the point or it was something very specific (maybe about another language since it was compilers class), but there is nothing above argv like other people said in this thread. However, it is still very cool that I've learnt about what AFTER argv. I will post something if I find out more. Messing with overflows and memory in C is a lot of fun.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, *BSD -- and hence Mac OS X -- and probably other unix-like systems, the `environ` array is constructed on the stack following the `argv` array.

`environ` contains all the environment variables as an array of strings each of the form `name=value`. While individual environment variables are generally accessed through the `getenv` function, use of the `environ` global variable is also permitted (by Posix).

Looking for these strings on the stack underneath the `main` call frame is *not* correct, nor does it offer any advantage over the use of `environ`.

If you want to look at the actual code, you'll need to dive into the implementation of the `execve` system call, which is what actually initiates a new process. There's what looks like a reasonably accurate discussion of the Linux process startup [here on lwn.org](https://lwn.net/Articles/630727/), which includes pointers to code repositories. The FreeBSD implementation, which is in many respects similar, is found in `/sys/kern/kern_exec.c`; you might start reading [here.](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/release/10.3.0/sys/kern/kern_exec.c?revision=297553&view=markup#l209)

Comment: Thank you very much rici. I did not know about `environ` and `getenv` function. It makes sense that reading it manually after argv is not safe or can't be reliable (like chux said as well). In my case I had no idea if there is anything so I tried reading as far as I can with different types to see if there is anything. I did not get a chance to look at `execve` yet. Finding this information about systems and how some operations happen (like what exactly happens when shell starts a program is oddly hard. I guess I should start looking at sources at some point. Thanks!

Comment: @serge the Posix documentation for execve is pretty precise about process startup, but does not specify how it is implemented. It's a good place to start reading, because it tells the requirement. The link in my answer talks about umplementation.